# PHP LDAP Admin - Undefined variable: _SESSION

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to install PHP LDAP Admin, http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net , on a RHEL 6 server.  I have the files in place and Apache virtual host directive configured to htdocs.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /path/to/pla/lib/page.php on line 381 Fatal error: 
Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /path/to/pla/lib/page.php on line 381
```

PHP (5.4.13) is running on the server, and sessions are not a problem elsewhere.  I cloned my git repository to an OSX development box and it works there.  I double checked and session_start() is called.

Comment: I have determined that when cloning the repo from git the config.php file was excluded (as it should be), but strange error as a result.  I added the config.php file and all is well.

Comment: Your `config.php` obviously contains _____.  Because of that, your error went away.  What is happening on line 381?

Comment: LIne 381: `if ($_SESSION[APPCONFIG]->getValue('appearance','minimalMode')) {`     I would have expected something like an undefined offset.

Answer (score 5):

If httpd is running under apache group:

```
chgrp apache /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally i solved it just placing config.php
in the correct folder (phpldapadmin/config)...really silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (ubuntu 14.04).

I changed the permissions on usr/share/phpldapadmin/config.php and that solved the problem.

This has already been answered by harveyzh but this answer is for linux-noobs like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Happens in most cases after update
 and apache (or php5-fpm!) didn't run with default users.

Just add the user wich is running Apache2 (or php5-fpm!) to the system group "www-data" (debian) and restart services apache AND if used php5-fpm both.

Get the User apache is running as:

```
~# sed -rn 's/^User (.+)/\1/p' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Remember:
 Changing permissions to repo maintained files is a bad idea.
 This takes effect only until the next update fixes them back to default...

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem where we have just changed the group name for phpldapadmin config.php file. It worked for me.

chgrp apache /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `chgrp` GNU command with the group name of apache2
In my case was: `www-data`

So you need to do like that:

```
chgrp www-data /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
```

to find group name of config.php you should use `ls -l` command line and take the fourth column